# how to serialize a json string to a form post data

Tags: c#, json.net

I need to POST a JSON string to a page.
The page is external and out of my control, and it expects the post data to be in the web-form post format (`key1=value1&key2=value2`)

How can I convert the JSON string to this format?

Comment: if you're posting it, it'll show up as a normal post field - json is just text, after all. e.g. `$data = json_decode($_POST['name_of_field_you_posted_the_json_as'])`

Comment: I'm confused. You want to POST it but you use the GET format as an example.

Comment: @MarcB isn't that PHP? what if the page expects just 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' format? ('key=value' pairs separated by &)

Comment: @ArlaudAgbePierre that's the standard format when a HTML form is posting the data to a page

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This can be done by first deserializing your JSON to a `Dictionary<string, string>`, then iterating through the key-value pairs in the dictionary and building up a querystring from that.

However, keep in mind that querystring format (`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`) is not a hierarchical format, while JSON is.  So your JSON object can only be a simple object with key-value pairs (no arrays or nested objects).  If your JSON is more complicated than that, you will have to do some more work to flatten it before you can convert it to a querystring.

Demo:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = @"
        {
            ""key1"" : ""value1"",
            ""key2"" : ""value2"",
            ""int"" : 5,
            ""bool"" : true,
            ""decimal"" : 3.14,
            ""punct"" : ""x+y=z""
        }";

        var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in dict)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(kvp.Key) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(kvp.Value))
            {
                if (sb.Length > 0) sb.Append('&');
                sb.Append(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(kvp.Key));
                sb.Append('=');
                sb.Append(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(kvp.Value));
            }
        }
        var postDataString = sb.ToString();

        Console.WriteLine(postDataString);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
key1=value1&key2=value2&int=5&bool=True&decimal=3.14&punct=x%2by%3dz
```

---

As was mentioned in the comments, you can use the [`FormUrlEncodedContent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.formurlencodedcontent?view=netframework-4.8) class to do the same thing.  Replace the `StringBuilder` and `foreach` loop in the code above with the following (but note this approach requires `async/await`):

```
var formUrlEncodedContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(dict);
var postDataString = await formUrlEncodedContent.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: thanks. I was looking for a method in the framework. but your answer is the most complete.

Comment: The FormUrlEncodedContent method can convert your dictionary to the form string. The whole foreach can be replaced by:
    string urlencodedformdata = new FormUrlEncodedContent(dict);

Answer (score 1):

You don't post JSON like that. You set the Content-Type header to "application/json" and then you simply fill the content body with the JSON as-is.

There is no built in support in C# or JSON.NET to serialize JSON into form post data, but you can probably use LINQ to JSON to write a translater yourself relatively easy, assuming the JSON format is simple enough.

Comment: what if the page expects just a 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' format? ('key=value' pairs separated by &)

Comment: Well, I assume you could just put the whole JSON string in a key, but honestly, if the page doesn't expect JSON, it's not going to work anyway. You post JSON to pages expecting JSON.

Comment: actually my question was how to serialize a JSON string to a form post data. The page is an external resource, I do not have control of it

Answer (score 1):

Is the Json being passed in always the same?  Your best bet is to deserialize the Json to a C# class then create your post data from that.